# No module named OpenSSL in kivy app

Tags: python, openssl, kivy, autobahn

I have a kivy app which actually based on [this example](https://github.com/crossbario/crossbarexamples/tree/master/kivy) .
In my desktop it works perfectly but when I build it whit buildozer and run it in my android device i get this error - ImportError: No module named OpenSSL

Here is my buildozer requirements section:

```
# comma seperated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = openssl,kivy,twisted,autobahn,ws4py
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`openssl` is the recipe which builds the openssl C library, not a Python module. You need the C library as well, but to get the Python module add `pyopenssl` to your requirements.